# Querying embedded document array giving wrong answer

Tags: json, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. Here is my JSON document

```
> 
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59ee168f9da785077ed9359d"),
"recordid" : 500,
"metadata" : [
    {
        "field" : 1,
        "values" : [
            100,
            102,
            110,
            151,
            804
        ]
    },
    {
        "field" : 2,
        "values" : [
            201,
            202,
            151
        ]
    },
    {
        "field" : 3,
        "values" : [
            350,
            351
        ]
    }
]
}
> 
>
```

I am trying to use the $and operator in a query so that I retrieve 0 for the following query. It returns 1 however. 1 is the correct answer, but not what I want.

```
... 
... 
> 
> db.test.find( {
...                     $and:[  
...                             {"metadata.field": 2},
...                             {"metadata.values": { $in: [654,804]}},
...                             {recordid: 500}
...                          ]
...                   }
...                ).count()
1
> 
>
```

I know why it is returning 1 result. It is because the "value" of 804 exists in `field: 1`.

What I want is for the query to return 0 results because `field: 2` has neither of the values 654 and 804 in the "value" field (it only has 151, 201 and 202).

What am I doing wrong?

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples) operator:

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

For example:

```
db.test.find({
    recordid: 500,
    // only match those sub documents in the metadata array which have field=2 
    // and a score of either 654 or 804
    metadata: { $elemMatch: { field: "2", score: { $in: [654, 804] } } }
})
```